When to include random-effects in zero-inflation model component?
Is it appropriate to specify random-effects (RE) in zero-inflation (ZI) component of the model? My intuition is that whatever RE is appropriate for main component should be appropriate for ZI component (since it is the same dataset that both are being modelled to). However, the answer stated in this post makes me question whether my intuition is correct. Could someone provide a practical example showing when specifying the same RE in both the main component and the ZI component of the model may be inappropriate? I am modelling my data with glmmTMB.

Note that the answer you linked only warns for technical problems with such models (more random effects being more difficult to fit), it otherwise says that it's appropriate if you believe it to be.


Is it appropriate to specify random-effects (RE) in zero-inflation (ZI) component of the model?

It certainly can be!  So long as the zero inflation is not entirely determined by the unit for which the random effect belongs, one could in principle include a random effect for the zero inflation part.
The zero inflation part of the model specifies some probability $\theta(z)$, which depends on covariates $z$.  All units have the same probability of observing the 0 within strata defined by z.  That being said, there may be additional variance to be explained away were you to observe the same unit multiple times.
Consider the following example:  Fishermen can decide if they would like to go fishing or not.  If they do decide to go fishing, then they can catch 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., fish.  Because deciding not to go fishing means the fisherman catch 0 fish (because they didn't go) we have a zero inflated process.
Suppose the probability to go fishing depends on if it is raining.  Even on rainy days, some fisherman may be more resilient to the rain than others, and may decide to go despite the rain.
Were we to observe these fishermen over multiple days, it might be sensible to include a random effect for fisherman in the zero inflation part of the model.
